# Map RouteData.Values parameters to controller parameter in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

In .NET 4.5 if I added anything to the RouteValueDictionary in RouteData.Values I could resolve this in the controller by adding it as an in-parameter for the controller but this doesn't seem to work in .NET Core.

This is my IRouter's RouteAsync method:

```
public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
{
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    var model = GetMyModel();
    if (model == null)
    {
        await _target.RouteAsync(context);
        return;
    }
    context.RouteData.Values["mymodel"] = model;
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"controller", pageController.Name.Replace("Controller", string.Empty)},
        {"action", "Index"},
        {"mymodel", model }
    };

    var tokenValues = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"mymodel", model }
    };
    // Set our values to the route data. 
    // Don't do it when creating the snapshot as we'd like them to be there after the restore as well.
    foreach (var tokenValueKey in tokenValues.Keys)
    {
        context.RouteData.DataTokens[tokenValueKey] = tokenValues[tokenValueKey];
    }
    foreach (var routeValueKey in routeValues.Keys)
    {
        context.RouteData.Values[routeValueKey] = routeValues[routeValueKey];
    }

    // This takes a snapshot of the route data before it is routed again
    var routeDataSnapshot = context.RouteData.PushState(_target, routeValues, tokenValues);

    try
    {
        await _target.RouteAsync(context);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Restore snapshot
        routeDataSnapshot.Restore();
    }
}
```

After this, my controller is in fact called but the parameter mymodel is just a default value, not the value I set in the router. If I look at the RouteData.Values the key "mymodel" is there and has a value. Why isn't the in-parameter also set to this? Do I need to add some middleware for model binding?

```
public IActionResult Index(MyModelClass mymodel)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`RouteData` is accessible through the controller instance as a property.

```
public class SomeControllerController : Controller {
    public IActionResult Index() {
        if (base.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("mymodel") == false) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        MyModel model = (MyModel) base.RouteData.Values["mymodel"];
        //LOGIC...
        return Index(model);
    }
}
```

For a cleaner imlementation you could create an abstract controller to do this.

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.routedata(v=vs.118).aspx